# Deploying to Glassfish from Eclipse, no classes included

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, buildpath

I am attempting to deploy a Java application from Eclipse (Version: Indigo Release, Build id: 20110615-0604) to Glassfish 3.1 using the Eclipse server adapter. When deploying, Glassfish throws a ClassNotFound exception on one of the classes in my applications.

When I look at the classes folder on my domain (glassfishroot/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/myApp/WEB-INF/classes) there are no classes there. There are empty folders for all the packages, but there are no files in them.

Why aren't my classes loaded into Glassfish, and what can I do to fix it?

EDIT:
If I clean and build the projects, the generated .class files are found in the project folder in Eclipse (project_root/build/classes/) so I know the build process is working.

EDIT 2:
Question resolved, see my answer below.

Comment: Try cleaning and building your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and in hindsight I feel rather stupid.

I had compilation errors in some of my Java classes. Once they were fixed, everything worked smoothly.

Sorry to have bothered you. Carry on with whatever you were doing.

Comment: I was going to ask you, if you getting any errors or exceptions while compiling. But you solved your self. Good.

Comment: If this is the answer, then you should accept it, or if you feel it's not useful enough for others, you can delete it.

Comment: Indeed. I've had to wait till now though, because site won't let you accept your own anser for the first two days after a question has been posted.